# Is it possible to combine two IF(AND functions into one? (OpenOffice Calc 4.1.7)

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, autocomplete, openoffice-calc

Is it possible to combine two IF/AND functions into one? (OpenOffice Calc)

I have two IF/AND functions that work perfectly well, however I need them to both work on the same line. Is there anyway to accomplish this? I am a complete noob to OpenOffice Calc and any help would be truly appreciated.

In any row, column D receives the input of either BUY or SELL.
The calculations for each are different and the answer is displayed in column P.

```
=IF(AND(D15="Buy";N15>99);((H15+i15)*M15);((O15-(H15+i15))*M15))
=IF(AND(D14="Sell";N14>99);((H14+i14)*M14);((H14+i14)*M14)-O14)
```

I would love it when I enter either BUY or SELL in D, the proper calculation would take place and display in column P.

My back up plan would be to add a column after N.
Column N would carry one function and new column O the other.
I really do not want to do this as I really do not want to extend the worksheet to a third page.
If I was forced to do this, how could I have the proper box (N or O) be automatically highlighted when either BUY or SELL was entered into D?

For example, if I enter BUY in D10, N10 would display a border around it.
(N is where the variable goes that triggers the second half of the form.
Either 100 or something less.)

Thank you in advance to any OpenOffice genius who could help me out

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest IF statements so you might want to try something like:

```
=IF(AND(D15="Buy";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);IF(AND(D15="Sell";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);((O15-(H15+I15))*M15)))
```

In Excel you can only nest IFs to 7 levels, I'm not sure if it is the same for OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

**Update**

Following on from the comments, my maths was failing me yesterday. You might be have to get a little hacky at the end and crowbar in another IF statement:

```
=IF(AND(D15="Buy";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);IF(AND(D15="Sell";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);IF(D15="Buy";((O15-(H15+I15))*M15);(((H15+I15)-O15)*M15))))
```

The first two IFs are choosing which formula to apply if `N15` is over 99. The last IF chooses which formula to apply if `N15` is under 99.

Comment: Thank you so much Burgi, for taking the time to help me out. I feel we are so close but not just there yet. In the SELL section, the ((O15-(H15+i15))*M15)) is actually (((H15+i15)-O15)*M15))
I made the change and all is well there.

In the BUY section, the ((O15-(H15+I15))*M15) is missing.
I tried to add it but the results return as Err:508

This is what I tried:
=IF(AND(D15="Buy";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);((O15-(H15+I15))*M15));IF(AND(D15="Sell";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);((H15+I15)-O15)*M15))

Comment: / Part 2 - 
Interestingly enough, when I remove the second half,
;IF(AND(D15="Sell";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);((H15+I15)-O15)*M15))
then the
=IF(AND(D15="Buy";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);((O15-(H15+I15))*M15))
does work.
What did I do wrong? (How can I add a screen cap to this comment?)

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Oops! I stupidly assumed they came to the same result. My excuse is that I was very tired.

Comment: You did it! Thank you so much! Words can not express how much you helped me out and how much I appreciate your time. Thank you! After quite a bit of testing all possible scenarios (I think), I had some final tweaking to do but I could have never done it without your formula. The final formula that works is:
<pre><code>IF(AND(D15="Buy";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);IF(AND(D15="Sell";N15>99);((H15+I15)*M15);IF(D15="Buy";(((N15-(H15+I15))*M15));(((H15+I15)-N15)*M15))))</code></pre>
I never received a notice you had replied, that's why it took me a few days to post again.
THANK YOU Burgi!!!